# concurrent modification exception on using addall and removeall on same arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have to remove a sublist from the `ArrayList` and add the same in begining. I am using below code -

```
for(int i =0 ;i <m ; i++){
    List<Integer> t = q.subList(j, k);
    q.removeAll(t);
    q.addAll(0, t);
}
```

I am getting concurrent exception modification on `addAll`. I tried creating a copy list from q and then calling `addAll` on that, still it throws the error on same line.

```
for(int i =0 ;i <m ; i++){
    List<Integer> t = q.subList(j, k);
    q.removeAll(t);
    ArrayList<Integer> q1= new ArrayList<Integer>(q);
    q1.addAll(0, t);
}
```

How can I perform both actions on same data list?

Comment: What is `i` and what is `m`?

Comment: It means you must be updating the collection during iteration. You can't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc of `subList` states that:

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

This means calling `removeAll` may invalidate the list returned by `subList`.

In addition, the Javadoc of `addAll` states that:

> The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (**Note that this will occur if the specified collection is this list, and it's nonempty**.)

And in your case, the `Collection` you are passing to `addAll` is the sub-list, which is backed by the original `List` on which you are calling `addAll`.

What you can do is store the elements of the sub-list in a separate `List` (`copyOfSubList`), use `clear()` to remove the elements of the sub-list (which will remove them also from the original `List`) and then add the elements of `copyOfSubList` back to the original `List`:

```
for(int i =0 ;i < m ; i++) {
    List<Integer> t = q.subList(j, k);
    List<Integer> copyOfSubList = new ArrayList<> (t);
    t.clear ();
    q.addAll(0, copyOfSubList);    
}
```

Comment: when we call t.clear(), it is still modifying the original list q. How come we can call q.addAll(0, copyOfSublist) after that?

Comment: @G.D `copyOfSublist` is a new List which is not related to the original List. Therefore it is not affected by `t.clear()`, and can be safely passed to `q.addAll`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) instead of `ArrayList`.
Iterators of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` never throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. When an iterator is created, it keeps a copy of the list's contents.