# Is there a java Collection where multiple non-overlapping subLists can modify the backing Lists and remain useable?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

The following code faces the same problem faced by [G.D in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744092/concurrent-modification-exception-on-using-addall-and-removeall-on-same-arraylis). Basically, multiple sublists can't modify a backing list. 

For example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     SOtest(); 
   }

      /*a test for stack overflow. Trying to find the right data structure*/
   public static void SOtest(){
      int[] gers = {1,3,2,4};
      ArrayList<Integer> name = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int i:gers)name.add(i);

      List firstSL = name.subList(0,2);
      List secondSL = name.subList(2,name.size());

      firstSL.remove(0);
      secondSL.remove(0);

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstSL.toArray()));
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondSL.toArray()));

   }
}
```

This code will cause a ConcurrentModificationException because firstSL and secondSL both use .remove.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.remove(ArrayList.java:1054)
    at TestClass.SOtest(TestClass.java:26)
    at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:13)
```

One solution to this is copying the subLists into new arrays like so:

```
    ...
ArrayList<Integer> firstSL = new ArrayList<Integer>(name.subList(0,2));
ArrayList<Integer> secondSL = new ArrayList<Integer>(name.sublist(2,name.size());
```

However, I'd like to avoid this solution because I need to do this operation a lot and copying takes too much time. 
*The subLists I'm creating will never overlap* so I don't see why this is a problem. 
 for example I'll never have

```
name = [1,2,3,4] 
firstSL = [1,2]
secondSL = [2,3,4]
```

**Is there a Collection that has this behavior?**

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I'll try to elaborate. The entire behavior I need is: an ordered collection that has the above ability to be sublisted, accessed by an index, give its size and removed by an index. 

I doubt this is useful, but it will be used in the MergeSort subClasses of this sorting algorithm github.com/user-name-is-taken/Merge_sort.

Comment: It would probably help if you can elaborate a bit more on what you want to achieve. The Java classes are what they are, but maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Better edit your question than adding comments.

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  `List#subList` explicitly calls this sort of thing out as [being "undefined" if the backing list is disturbed in any way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is *structurally modified* in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

If you want something like this, you'll have to engineer your own solution.  What you have is a decent start, but you may want to encapsulate it in a proper object on your own.